# Different return values in chrome and IE for date?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In chrome fucntion returns me false and in IE returns me true.Any suggestion why is that happening?I posted image to see what i get.
[image]

```
var _convertFromUTC = function(ticketTimeCreated) {
    var offset = new Date(ticketTimeCreated).getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var hours = new Date(ticketTimeCreated).getHours();

    ticketTimeCreated = new Date(ticketTimeCreated).setHours(hours - offset);
         return new Date(ticketTimeCreated);
      }

    var _checkForTimeDiference = function(ticketTimeCreated) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var formatedDate = _convertFromUTC(ticketTimeCreated);
    if (formatedDate.getDate() == currentDate.getDate() && formatedDate.getHours() == currentDate.getHours())
    if (currentDate.getMinutes() - formatedDate.getMinutes() <= mainConfigService.TicketCancelDuration) {
           return true;
      }

          return false;
   }
```

Comment: `currentDate` should be UTC, right ?

Comment: @Hacketo any suggestion? :)

Comment: Could try to check if `currentDate = new Date()` return the same date for both browser. Also check the `if` syntax with the braces

Comment: Mon Aug 24 2015 16:17:20 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)  that i get in both browsers for currentDate

Answer (score 0):

As you used an UTC timestamp you don't need to convert it, [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will do it for you

```
new Date("2015-08-24T13:10:56") // Mon Aug 24 2015 15:10:56 GMT+0200
```

a simple function like this should be ok

```
var _checkForTimeDiference = function(ticketTimeCreated) {
  var currentDate = +new Date; // number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970
  var ticketDate = +new Date(ticketTimeCreated);
  return (currentDate  - ticketDate) <= mainConfigService.TicketCancelDuration * (1000*60);
}
```